# submitting a snakemake job to the cluster from within a ('correct') conda environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, snakemake

I am writing a snakemake file that shall perform multiple operations on multiple samples. After I validated the workflow running on my local computer, I am now working on running the workflow on a cluster.

My first two rules are independent from one another, the first uses `fastqc` and the other `bwa mem`

These two rules look like (at this point I am only calling the workflow on a single `SAMPLE = 'NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample'`):

```
rule fastQC:
    input:
        R1 = FQDIR + "{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz",
        R2 = FQDIR + "{sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz"
    output:
        directory("fastQC/{sample}")
    conda:
        "envs/NIPTlibPrep.yaml"
    log:
        "logs/fastQC/{sample}.log" # log was giving an error when running at the command line
    shell:
        # 2> {log} at the end of the command removed
        # See wrapper at https:/snakemake-wrappers.readthedocs.io/en/stable/wrappers/fastqc.html
        "mkdir -p fastQC/{wildcards.sample} | fastqc --outdir fastQC/{wildcards.sample} -f fastq {input.R1} {input.R2}"


rule bwa_map: 
    input:
        R1 = FQDIR + "{sample}_R1_001.fastq.gz",
        R2 = FQDIR + "{sample}_R2_001.fastq.gz",
        REF = config['ref']    
    output:
        # wrap output in temp
        "aligned/{sample}.bam"
    log:
        "logs/bwa_mem/{sample}.log" 
    conda:
        "envs/NIPTlibPrep.yaml"
    shell:
        "bwa mem {input.REF} {input.R1} {input.R2} "
        "| samtools view -Sb - > {output} 2> {log}"
```

But when I call:

```
snakemake -p -s Snakefile_v4_ngs_bngs05b --cluster qsub -j 5 --use-conda
```

I get:

```
Error in rule bwa_map:
    jobid: 10
    output: aligned/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample.bam
    log: logs/bwa_mem/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample.log (check log file(s) for error message)
    conda-env: /nexusb/nipt/200311_A00154_0454_AHHHKMDRXX/testMetrics/outSnakeMake_test/.snakemake/conda/38107c2c
    shell:
        bwa mem /home/ngs/data/genomes/b37/human_g1k_v37.fasta /nexusb/Novaseq/200311_A00154_0454_AHHHKMDRXX/Unaligned/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample_R1_001.fastq.gz /nexusb/Novaseq/200311_A00154_0454_AHHHKMDRXX/Unaligned/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample_R2_001.fastq.gz | samtools view -Sb - > aligned/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample.bam 2> logs/bwa_mem/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample.log
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
    cluster_jobid: Your job 381368 ("snakejob.bwa_map.10.sh") has been submitted

Error executing rule bwa_map on cluster (jobid: 10, external: Your job 381368 ("snakejob.bwa_map.10.sh") has been submitted, jobscript: /nexusb/nipt/200311_A00154_0454_AHHHKMDRXX/testMetrics/outSnakeMake_test/.snakemake/tmp.bnhr7qck/snakejob.bwa_map.10.sh). For error details see the cluster log and the log files of the involved rule(s).
[Wed Apr  8 17:21:45 2020]
Error in rule fastQC:
    jobid: 1
    output: fastQC/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample
    log: logs/fastQC/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample.log (check log file(s) for error message)
    conda-env: /nexusb/nipt/200311_A00154_0454_AHHHKMDRXX/testMetrics/outSnakeMake_test/.snakemake/conda/38107c2c
    shell:
        mkdir -p fastQC/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample | fastqc --outdir fastQC/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample -f fastq /nexusb/Novaseq/200311_A00154_0454_AHHHKMDRXX/Unaligned/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample_R1_001.fastq.gz /nexusb/Novaseq/200311_A00154_0454_AHHHKMDRXX/Unaligned/NIPT-PearlPPlasma-03-PPx_S3downSample_R2_001.fastq.gz
        (one of the commands exited with non-zero exit code; note that snakemake uses bash strict mode!)
    cluster_jobid: Your job 381369 ("snakejob.fastQC.1.sh") has been submitted

Error executing rule fastQC on cluster (jobid: 1, external: Your job 381369 ("snakejob.fastQC.1.sh") has been submitted, jobscript: /nexusb/nipt/200311_A00154_0454_AHHHKMDRXX/testMetrics/outSnakeMake_test/.snakemake/tmp.bnhr7qck/snakejob.fastQC.1.sh). For error details see the cluster log and the log files of the involved rule(s).
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
```

Upon first execution of the workflow I noticed that the environment was created at `.snakemake/conda` (relative to the Snakefile). When I call the script for the second time, without changing the `conda` directives, snakemake uses the same `conda-env`.

The description of my environment looks like:

```
channels:
  - bioconda
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - bwa=0.7.17
  - samtools=1.9
  - picard=2.22.1
  - mosdepth=0.2.6
  - python=3.7.6
  - pandas=1.0.3
  - fastqc=0.11.9
```

and it is saved at `envs/NIPTlibPrep.yaml` (relative to the Snakefile)

The fact that the workflow finishes locally but cannot be run on the cluster I find really puzzling, especially considering the fact that the environment with the correct dependencies was successfully created.

Comment: What is the output/error message?

Comment: the only error message I am getting is shown on the question. The `log` directives in the rules are producing empty log files, unfortunately

Comment: So how do we know it is a conda issue? What if you touch the output. Does that work?

Comment: I have a strong suspicion it is related to the creation of the environment by submission with `qsub` because the full workflow finished w/o error when I run without the `--cluster` flag. I have replaced the `shell` directive in the `bwa_map` by `touch {output}` while that of fastQC was only `mkdir -p fastQC/{wildcards.sample}` and I got an identical error message.

Comment: So it still crashes? What if you do not use --use-conda, and just touch stuff? Are you sure the paths are correct?

Comment: It still crashes, yes. I dropped `--use-conda` and the shell directives on `bwa_map` and `fastqc` were only `mkdir` or `touch`. I am now suspecting that the qsub command is sending the jobs to machines in the cluster where conda is not installed. I am sure that the paths and the rest is OK as the workflow finishes in one node of the cluster where conda is installed. This works when I call snakemake from within the environment where all the programs and dependencies are installed

Comment: Bingo, the default `-q` parameter of `qsub` was submitting the jobs to multiple machines of our cluster, where conda was not installed. I specified the `-q` parameter to submit the job to a single machine (where conda is installed) and it worked

Comment: Nice, glad that it works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#integrated-package-management

You will have to make a make a conda environment yaml for the rule `sort_bam`, something like this:

```
channels:
  - bioconda
dependencies:
  - samtools
```

And then in your rule you need to refer to this file under the `conda` attribute:

```
rule sort_bam:
    input:
        "aligned/{sample}.bam"
    output:
        protected("aligned/{sample}.sorted.bam")
    params:
        THREADS = config['sort_threads']
    conda:
        "samtools.yaml"
    shell:
        "samtools sort -T aligned/{wildcards.sample} "
        "-O bam {input} > {output}"
```

Then you can call `snakemake -np -s Snakefile_v4_ngs_bngs05b --cluster qsub -j 5 --use-conda` and Snakemake will take care of the rest.

Comment: I have made the edits you suggested, though I am still getting errors, please see my edited question